# SQL empty IN statement

Tags: sql

What happens if I write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name IN (select name from someotherTable where id = 3)
```

and the inner query (inside the IN statement) returns no result set

will the outer where automatically evaluate to True or to False?

Comment: I don't know if you realize it or not, and I don't mean to be snarky, but you might've been able to find out conclusively on your own in less time that it took to post this question.

Answer (score 6):

This will return an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Let's test it;

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( id INT );
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE TableB ( id INT );
SELECT * FROM TableA
  WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM TableB);

(empty set)
```

Comment: But   `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id = ALL (SELECT * FROM TableB);` does return a result.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, as I'm sure you know, `ALL` returns true for empty sets (not to mention completely changes the meaning of the whole question :) )

Comment: Just thought I'd chuck that in there!